# How to join a grouped table in sql?

Tags: sql, hive

Novice in SQL here but hopefully someone can help. I have two tables. For the simplicity here is how the tables are structured.

Table 1:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| department | sales | date      | sales_code |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 50    | 5/26/2021 | A          |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| 2          | 150   | 5/26/2021 | B          |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 200   | 5/25/2021 | C          |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| 2          | 250   | 5/24/2021 | D          |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| item | department | sales | date      | column I want to join |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 31   | 1          | 50    | 5/26/2021 | x                     |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 30   | 2          | 150   | 5/26/2021 | x                     |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 29   | 1          | 200   | 5/25/2021 | x                     |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 28   | 2          | 250   | 5/24/2021 | x                     |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I need to join table 2 to table 1 - however it needs to be aggregated by department sales first, this is because table 2 is already aggregated by department sales. Here is what I was thinking but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN (
SELECT department, date, column_i_want, sum(sales)
FROM table2
GROUP BY department ) as t2
ON t2.department = t1.department AND t1.date = t2.date
```

Desired Output:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
| department | sales | date      | sales_code | column I want to join |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1          | 50    | 5/26/2021 | A          | x                     |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 2          | 150   | 5/26/2021 | B          | x                     |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1          | 200   | 5/25/2021 | C          | x                     |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 2          | 250   | 5/24/2021 | D          | x                     |
+------------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show us your desired output as well.

Comment: Start with the subquery. Does it return what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about doing that, the easiest one is to create a view

```
CREATE VIEW t2 AS
SELECT department, date, column_i_want, sum(sales)
FROM table2
GROUP BY department;
```

then it's easier to join them (you can also use a With clause instead of a view but it can get messy)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN t2
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what you want:

```
select t2.*, t1.sales_code
from table2 t2
join table1 t1
 on t1.department = t2.department
  and t1.date = t2.date
```